# Have trouble getting the toggle status from api & check it with status data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a toggle button with titles that is setting data to send to server.

And it is getting api data like what it is posted to server.
I want to check the if there is a similar item id in api data with rules then get its status and replace it with what it is right now.
But i get this error `changedStatus is not defined`
I would appreciate if someone can help me with it.

Link to my code in sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-todo-list-forked-4kui26

```
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="Rule.params.value" />

     Rules: [
    {
      item_id: 144,
      title: "_00_Init_Initialization",
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 145,
      title: "_Init_AppsInitialization",
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 146,
      title: "_02_Global_Generic",
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 147,
      title: "_02_Global_Generic",
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 148,
      title: "02_Global_Generic",
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 149,
      title: "Global_Generic",
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
  ],
  apiData: [
    {
      item_id: 144,
      params: {
        value: true,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 145,
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 146,
      params: {
        value: true,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 147,
      params: {
        value: true,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 148,
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
    {
      item_id: 149,
      params: {
        value: false,
      },
    },
  ],
```

in methods

```
 mounted() {
   console.log("mounted");
   this.checkStatus();
  },
 methods: {
   checkStatus() {
     this.Rules.map((rule) => {
     this.apiData.map((data) => {
      const status = this.apiData.find(
        (data) => rule.item_id == data.item_id
      );
      if (status.params.value == true) {
        const changedStatus = this.Rules.find(
          (data) => status.item_id == data.item_id
        );
        changedStatus.params.value = true
      } else {
        changedStatus.params.value = false
      }
    });
  });
},
```

Comment: The second `changedStatus` (in the `else`) is not in the scope of the block (only defined in the `if`). Define it out of the block and assign a value in the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define `changedStatus` outside of the condition:

```
methods: {
  checkStatus() {
    this.Rules.map((rule) => {
    this.apiData.map((data) => {
    const status = this.apiData.find(
      (data) => rule.item_id == data.item_id
    );
    const changedStatus = this.Rules.find(
      (data) => status.item_id == data.item_id
    );
    status.params.value == true ? 
      changedStatus.params.value = true : 
      changedStatus.params.value = false
    }
  });
});
```